# EntityFramework Select Most commented Images

Tags: c#, entity

I have an aspx web site with commented Images. The structure of tables is:

```
Table name: Images
int id (Primary Key)
varcharmax path(path of the image)

Table name: Comments
int picid; (Linked to image id)
Text text;
```

I need to select top 10 commented images using Entity Framework. How is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like:

```
var result = (from img in db.Images
              order by img.Comments.Count() descending
              select img).Take(10);
```

Or if, like me, you much prefer the other syntax (with methods)

```
var result = db.Images
               .OrderByDescending(img => img.Comments.Count())
               .Take(10);
```

Comment: Thereis no Commnents counter in Images.

Comment: Then you need to set up the association between `Images` and `Comments` in your entity model. Hint: If your database has the correct FK relationship it'll do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

This selects the top 10:

```
var result = (
  from i in db.Images
  order by i.Comments.Count() descending
  select i).Take(10);
```